# Can I repurpose an old ‘identify’ question?

Tags: discussion, identify

A while back I asked this question: [What movie is this set from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/what-movie-is-this-set-from)

Now `identify-this-movie` questions are being removed (which I welcome - I was never in favour of them but took advantage in that instance!). But I wonder, is it worth rewriting the question (and answer) slightly to be more a generic question about how to identify a movie from the set/location?

Comment: We will likely create a general ID guidance FAQ here on meta anyway (as proposed in one of the recent answers). Maybe it might be more productive to add any such insights there. (Besides that, that question doesn't look like it will likely get cleaned up anyway, seeing its votes and having an accepted answer.)

Comment: Is the set still up, or were you just lucky to visit it while production was going on? If the former, I think it ought be repurposable, though unfortunately I have no idea for doing so (as I managed to do with the recent [Is McConaughey's anecdote about not memorizing a four page monologue real?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84507)). If it's still around, then there's something much more concrete than "here's this arbitrary list of stuff I remember" that someone else might ask about.

Comment: @Josh I *think* it’s a fairly generic Western set that was probably modified a little for each movie filmed there.

Comment: I would think you can edit it, then; "What's the deal with this permanent movie set in Wherever, NM?"